# Selenium (Powershell) Run as a different user

Tags: powershell, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to start Selenium (Google Chrome - WebDriver) as a different user and I am pretty much lost as I don't know where to add $mycreds. This is quite easy to achieve if I want to start a normal Chrome session, however, I am stuck when it comes to achieving this using Selenium. Any advice ?

```
$username = "domain\name"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $password
$Driver = Start-SeChrome
Enter-SeUrl -Url 'https://www.google.com/' -Driver $Driver
```

If I try to pass it along using -Arguments , it will still use my account to open the browser without returning any error.

```
$Driver = Start-SeChrome -Arguments $mycreds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to do this is by starting Powershell as-another-user instead. Make sure you have the module set up for that user as well as any other environment stuff you might need.

The [selenium-powershell](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell/) module itself does not support starting the selenium drivers as a different  user from the current one.

---

You may also want to make sure you're using an updated version of the module as well, since (in [pre-release](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell/blob/master/Output/Selenium/ChangeLog.md)):

> `Start-SeChrome` and other have been removed in favor of `Start-SeDriver -Browser Chrome` (#100)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. There is a slight problem with this approach. The account in question is actually a server account running on Microsoft Windows Server 2012.

Comment: @Jin The recommendation should still be the same, unless you're trying to either run it *as* the computer account or start selenium over a remote session?

Comment: Managed to deal with it this way. Thanks for your help